# Does bash echo show up in ps

Tags: bash, echo, stdin, ps

I'm trying to pass sensitive data to stdin using bash **script**.
I was wondering if I can use

```
echo "This is verysecretmessage" | IamAwaitingStdin
```

I thought that since `echo` is `/bin/bash` built-in it should not show up in `ps` or anywhere else, is that correct?

If not, and for example, this will work **instead of** the solution above

```
IamAwaitingStdin <<EOF
This is verysecretmessage
EOF
```

Then how can I use `<<EOF bla bla EOF` syntax in bash script when encapsulating it with ()? What is the syntax?

I guess this one is not correct since bash is one-liner

```
$(IamAwaitingStdin << EOF
This is verysecretmessage
EOF)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What program requires (and lets) you to pass plaintext data in via stdin? Programs with strong security will have more secure methods than this. `ssh` for example tries very hard to prevent you from passing secret data in via stdin precisely so that you aren't tempted to embed passwords on the command-line or in scripts.

Comment: You are perfectly right John. Yet, this is a school task thus it's non-negotiable. I will point it out to the tutor, though I think he already is aware of that. (as stated here too http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/078)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are correct that an `echo` does not create a separate process.  The new process's name will come from the other side of the pipe.
2. Your example of `$(`...`)` with a here-document will work fine - most bash constructs can span multiple lines, even though they normally don't.  (At most you might need to escape some embedded newlines with `\`, but within `$(`...`)` even that's not necessary.)
3. You can also use a herestring instead of a heredoc:

   ```
   IamAwaitingStdin <<<"This is verysecretmessage"
   ```